# display only the values from a list after quering mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I was wondering if it is possible for me to only have the values displayed from the results of query which are returned in a list.

I am running the following:

```
a = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(list(db.bastion.find( { },{ 'counter': 1, '_id': False } ))))
```

Which returns something similar to this:

```
[{'counter': 10447}, {'counter': 25375}, {'counter': 11963}, {'counter': 17297},
 {'counter': 5893}, {'counter': 19955}, {'counter': 5159}, {'counter': 3988},
 {'counter': 7638}, {'counter': 8250}, {'counter': 29514}, {'counter': 4940},
 {'counter': 12834}, {'counter': 31153}, {'counter': 8588}, {'counter': 17585},
 {'counter': 7099}, {'counter': 18580}, {'counter': 2575}, {'counter': 3696},
 {'counter': 5071}, {'counter': 4074}, {'counter': 15355}, {'counter': 16520},
 {'counter': 13850}, {'counter': 18639}, {'counter': 22640}, {'counter': 13962},
 {'counter': 14354}, {'counter': 10945}, {'counter': 10330}]
```

So what I would like is just the values and not the key name counter displayed so I can calculate the 95th percentile doing the following:

```
for i in a:
  print np.percentile(map(int,i),95)
```

Comment: I think a mongo query cannot do this. So either you map client-side or use map-reduce.

Comment: Why the `ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(…))`? Seems completely redundant to me.

Comment: hi that was just to get rid of the u{XXXXXXX} from being displayed apart from that serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a ticket to add the percentile operator to the MongoDB Aggregation Framework.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7463

When released, you'll be able to do it entirely on the server-side.

For now, like hgoebl suggested, you'll have to do it client-side, or use map-reduce.

```
a = db.bastion.find( { }, { 'counter': 1, '_id': False } ))))

np.percentile([x['score'] for x in a], 95)
```

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, I updated the answer with a more appropriate way to declare the `a` variable.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you right, you want to get rid of the markup.
so try this then:

```
var ch = db.bastion.find( { },{ 'counter': 1, '_id': False }; ch.forEach( function(doc) {print(doc.counter);});
```

this will give you the clear values

Comment: Thanks Zali will give this a go now.

Comment: This is JavaScript, not Python.